# Migrate windows users to Linux server

Tags: linux, windows, migration

Needing to migrate a windows server to a Linux server (Ubuntu) with roughly 1000 users. Are there migration tools which can be used to transfer the windows accounts over, rather than manually? I've read Ubuntu has migration tools but there doesn't seem much detail about this

Comment: Are those local users or active directory  users?

Comment: active directory users

Comment: Are you getting rid of Windows entirely? What's the overall context for this migration?

Comment: @MichaelHampton getting rid of Windows as it's been requested

Comment: That's really very little to go on.

Comment: Do you plan to keep AD DS for directory and auth to Linux, or do you have something else to migrate that to?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use sssd and kerberos to join the Linux host to the AD domain.

Once that is configured correctly, you will have a name services plugin (sssd in /etc/nsswitch.conf) that will allow nss to query AD for the user details (ie. /etc/passwd contents).

Then you could use "getent passwd" to list the AD users in /etc/passwd format.  Simply direct this output to a file and then use that file to build your actual /etc/passwd on the local linux host.  You can create /etc/shadow entries from this same data, with locked hashes ("!!") initially.

Some caveats...

1. The users in AD will need to have their UNIX Attributes defined.  AD supports this natively in the User Properties panel (View advanced Features=on), Attribute Editor tab.  You will need to specify things like: gidNumber, name, uid, uidNumber, and unixHomeDirectory.  This will allow for a more complete /etc/passwd style output.

When setting things like uidNumber and gidNumber, be sure that you think through what these should be and that you have prepared the linux side accordingly.  Remember, do not duplicate uidNumber for any users.

2. Depending on your version of Windows Server, you may or may not be able to query the users hashed password.  I think MS removed this ability in Server 2012, but my memory there is fuzzy.  So, once the users are imported into Linux, you may need to have them set new passwords.
3. If you're lucky, you might also be able to grab some group data from Windows with "getent group", but it might not be usable.  Could be worth a try just to see what you get.

Please, please, please... don't use any capitalization in your linux /etc/passwd or /etc/group files.  Other than the user's real name (GECOS field), there should be no capital letters in these files.  Linux won't care, but it's totally outside of best-practices and screams "Amateur!"

After all of this is done, you can remove the sssd/kerberos configurations.

It's a bit involved, but it's probably quicker than manually recreating 1000 users by hand.